# Splitting HTML content into translatable chunks

Tags: php, html, google-translate

I am using the Google translate API to content, there are cases where the length of this content exceeds the limit Google imposes on the API calls.

Any one know the best way to split the content so that multiple requests could be used instead?
I'm concious that I don't want to break the html or the content in a way that makes it untranslatable.

Answer (score 1):

Well one of the solutions could be just splitting the content with JavaScript split function on "." or "!" or "?" or any other char that could end a sentence  (`content.split(".");`) Check that its length is less than API's limit and pass it to API sentence by sentence. This way you will not going to loose a context.

Comment: Unless of course s/he is in a locale where digits are represented with a "." and there are fraction numbers in the content.

Comment: The source language will always be english, so could work. Splitting on <p> and <br> as well would good also.